# MFC Toolbar on Dialog?

Tags: c++, mfc, toolbar

I have tried everything I can think of to get a toolbar to show up on my dialog... including trying to create it myself with `CreateWindow`.. but it won't show up

I created a dialog in the resource editor, and then made a class for it(tried deriving from both `CDialog` and `CDialogEx`). Isn't it possible to add a `CToolbar` control to it?

Comment: [DLGCBR32 Sample: Demonstrates Adding a Status Bar and Toolbar to Dialog Boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccstww6w%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there are four steps.

1, `CToolBar m_ToolBar; // Meanwhile you create a resource (e.g. IDR_TOOLBAR1)`

2, Call CToolBar's Create function

```
m_ToolBar.Create(this);
```

3, Call the `LoadToolBar` function

```
m_ToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR1);
```

4, The most important step, call `RepositionBars`

```
RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have never used the actual toolbar maker in the resource editor before, but after doing so, and adding a button, it became apparent to me that an empty default toolbar would be completely invisible on a dialog...unlike a frame window(with a dark gray background) >.<